# Making a web link clickable in a textview (of a ListItem)

Tags: android

In the `ListView Adapter's getView()` function I have this:

```
holder.comment.setText(Html.fromHtml(comment));
holder.comment.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

`holder.comment` is a `TextView`.

In the Activity which contains this ListView, I have implemented `onItemClick Listener`. Which worked until I enabled

```
holder.comment.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Now the item click listener is not working, as if this line of code overrode the click behavior. The click event works only on the `TextView (holder.comment)` which opens the Link in a browser. Clicking on any other part of the `ListView` Item doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

```
commentsListView
    .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this,"" + arg2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How you are using onItemClick ? Paste your code.

Comment: ummm try this but i am not sure if it will work on Listview, i tried it on expendableListView, add this to the ACTIVITY manifest, <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" .... > and add this  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to the textview XML. hope it works

Comment: @Prince Its a very simple. Check the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any row item of list contains `Focusable` or `Clickable` view then OnItemClickListener won't work.

row item must be having param like

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

your `list_item.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

// your other TextView and Other widget here

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It because content of row xml block the click event of listview, simple add [descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3adescendantFocusability) property to  `main layout of row xml.`

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"